# How I keep a text modified by JavaScript during an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, text, scriptmanager

I have a textbox with `autopostback = true` and I have a JavaScript function to validate it. The JavaScript function also does a little format when the value is OK, but when I call it from PageRequestManager add_beginRequest or add_initializeRequest, the value is changed after the process.  How can I do this?

First I control the request:

```
try {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    }
    catch (e) { }
```

Then I have my handler calling the validation function and I pass the type of validation I want. then precallbackvalidation is my custom validation function and if there is an error, it will reject the partial postback, but if the validation it's OK, the validation function has already made some format inside my textbox which is lost after the postback.

```
function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    if (typeof precallbackvalidation == 'function') {
        if ($(args._postBackElement).attr("PreCallBackIndex") != null) {
            if (!precallbackvalidation(args._postBackElement)) {
                args.set_cancel(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how to format my text by JavaScript and not losing it after the postback.

```
<asp:textbox ID="txtRut" runat="server" MaxLength="13" size="13" Width="75px" TabIndex="1" AutoPostBack="true" PreCallBackIndex="rutcte" ></asp:textbox>
```

On my page I have the textbox with the attribute to trigger the validation, and the validation function.

```
function precallbackvalidation(obj) {
    var index = $(obj).attr("PreCallBackIndex");
    if ($(obj).length > 0) {
        switch (index) {
            case 'rutcte':
                return ValidarTipo('rut', obj, true);                    
                break;
            case 'ptjegastos':
                if (ValidarTipo('entero', obj)==false) {
                    if (ValidarTipo('real', obj)==false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
                break;
            case 'ptjemargen':
                if (ValidarTipo('entero', obj) == false) {
                    if (ValidarTipo('real', obj) == false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
                break;
            case 'ptjeppm':
                if (ValidarTipo('entero', obj) == false) {
                    if (ValidarTipo('real', obj) == false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
                break;
            case 'ptjecomision':
                if (ValidarTipo('entero', obj) == false) {
                    if (ValidarTipo('real', obj) == false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
                break;
            default:
                return true;
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `ValidarTipo` (or `ValidateTypes` in English) is a generic function in JavaScript which does the format for the 'rut' option; but that format is lost after the all process ends

When I write "19" inside the textbox, the JavaScript function format this text to "1-9", but then when the request process continues after the `beginrequest` or `initializerequest`, the AJAX process seems to clear the JavaScripts modifications and let my text back to "19"

Comment: What does the `EndRequestHandler` do? Please share it's code as well.